# Qt5: Calling .bat file with QProcess::startDetached doesn't find program in System32

Tags: c++, windows, qt, batch-file

I have a small Qt GUI program with a button, that starts a .bat file.

The important part to call the .bat is this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int r = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Shutdown System"),
    tr("Do you want to close the program and the system?"),
    QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Default,
    QMessageBox::No,
    QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Escape);

    if (r == QMessageBox::Yes){
        QProcess::startDetached("cmd /C shutdown_all.bat");
    }
}
```

I intend to call [PSShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psshutdown.aspx), located in `C:\Windows\System32\psshutdown.exe`, and of course in the `PATH`.

I put this in the .bat for testing purposes:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
psshutdown
PAUSE
```

When the .bat file is called alone, seems to find the program and print info about it, but when I use the button to call the program, it can't find `psshutdown.exe`

Captures of the results:

Calling .bat with Qt program:
[image: .bat called from Qt program]

Calling .bat with double click (expected result):
[image]

The path also seems to be printed Ok in both versions when adding `echo %PATH%` to the .bat. Any idea what could be wrong?

This has been tested with Qt 5.5 and 5.7, debug and release mode, in two different computers.

I can provide the full source code if needed, but it's just a Qt Widgets Aplication with an added button, using the template in Qt Creator.

Comment: Would like to know what happens when you specify the full path to the executable in the batch file. **C:\windows\system32\psshutdown.exe**

Comment: Hello @Squashman, still not found. A workaround I found it's if I copy the executable to the same folder, calling psshutdown works, but that's a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: If you are running a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system, you might be a victim of [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx). Try copying `psshutdown.exe` into `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64`, if you don't encounter the error after copying, then this is the case. . .

Comment: your code should work ! have you tried to start any other exe rather than psshutdown.exe ? or any other exe outside of system32 ?

Comment: Thank you @Mike, your suggestion actually worked! Feel free to post it as an answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: @HAG exes outside System32 works, Mike pointed it, copying the exe to SysWOW64 worked like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psshutdown.exe` is an executable which usually does not exist on Windows. It is a tool from [Windows Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) which needs to be downloaded and copied manually to any directory.

On 64-bit Windows 64-bit applications accesses the 64-bit applications and dynamic linked libraries in `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

But Windows [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) redirects x86 applications running on 64-bit Windows to the 32-bit system directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` on accessing `%SystemRoot%\System32` for running an executable or loading a DLL.

One solution is using following code in batch file:

```
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\psshutdown.exe (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\psshutdown.exe
) else if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\psshutdown.exe (
    %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\psshutdown.exe
) else if %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\psshutdown.exe (
    %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\psshutdown.exe
) else (
    echo Error: Can't find psshutdown.exe in system directory of Windows.
    pause
)
```

This batch code works independent on compiling the Qt application as x64 or x86 application for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows and independent into which system directory `psshutdown.exe` was copied before.

The first **IF** condition is for 32-bit applications on 32-bit Windows with only `System32` and 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows with 64-bit `System32` and 32-bit `SysWOW64`.

The second **IF** condition is for 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows for accessing 64-bit `System32`.

The third **IF** condition is for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows for accessing 32-bit `SysWOW64`.

Another solution is copying the file `psshutdown.exe` with a 64-bit file manager like Windows Explorer to the two directories

```
%SystemRoot%\System32
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64
```